# dataTable gives Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm trying to use jQuery Datatable plugin for my pagination in the HTML page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src=" https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src=" https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Clients</title>
</head>
<body>
<table style="width:100%" id="clients_data">
<caption>Clients</caption>
  <tr>
    <th>Clients</th>
    <th>Number of Sites</th> 
    <th>Reset the Processing</th> 
  </tr>
  </table>

<table style="width:100%" id="machines_data">
<caption>Machines</caption>
  <tr>
   <th>Number</th>
    <th>Machine Name</th>
  </tr>
  </table>

$(document).ready(function() {
     loadCustomers();
     loadMachines();
    $('#clients_data').DataTable( {
        "pagingType": "full_numbers"
    } );
    $('#machines_data').DataTable( {
        "pagingType": "full_numbers"
    } );

} );


function loadCustomers() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/cache/getCustomers',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            var rows = [];    
            $.each(data,function(id,value) {
                      rows.push('<tr><td><a href="clientSiteInfo.html?client='+id+'">'+id+'</td><td>'+value+'</td><td><button type="button" onclick="reset(\''+id+'\')">Reset</td></tr>');
                    });
            $('#clients_data').append(rows.join(''));
        }
    });
};

function loadMachines() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/cache/getMachines',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
             var rows = [];    
             $.each(data,function(id,value) {
                      rows.push('<tr><td>'+id+'</td><td><a href="machineInfo.html?machine='+value+'">'+value+'</td></tr>');
                    });
             $('#machines_data').append(rows.join(''));

        }
    });
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

For the above, when I try to load page I'm getting:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined at $('#clients_data').DataTable({...})

What is wrong in my script?
I'm following [this guide](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/alt_pagination.html).

My fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/yeu7f3f2/

Comment: My advice is please use DataTable after ajax loading it is async request and your rows.push didnt finish then you try to set datatable.

Comment: @FerhatBAŞ , How should I order this? n the document ready I try to call ajax functions first..Is that wrong?

Comment: Please nove this code in ajax success after .append function $('#clients_data').DataTable( { "pagingType": "full_numbers" } );

Comment: @FerhatBAŞ Same error I get..I changed like  $('#clients_data').append(rows.join('')).DataTable( { "pagingType": "full_numbers" } );

Comment: Handle the data in the server side, not with `rows.push`. It will slow down the process if you have larger number of records. Can you create a fiddle? so that we can easily check the issue

Comment: Can you seperate last code append and datatable

Comment: I don't see any script tag opened for javascript and I found that you are using jquery plugin twice

Comment: @LingasamySakthivel here is fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/yeu7f3f2/

Comment: @FerhatBAŞ here is fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/yeu7f3f2/, I seperated but no difference

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined`

typically means the **number of headers** and the **number of columns of data** do not match.

Comment: @DonBhrayanSingh My table loads data without  any issue, if I dont use that dataTable pagination

Comment: Hi, Your problem is in html table  please add thead and tbody like below <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Clients</th>
    <th>Number of Sites</th> 
    <th>Reset the Processing</th> 
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>dsds</td>
    <td>dsds</td>
    <td>dsds</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>

Comment: @FerhatBAŞ thanks that was the issue.It works now.What is wrong with my previous table definition?

Comment: I think it is required for DataTable, I think it couldnt find to which DOM elemeny DATA or HEADER hence can't do it

Comment: @FerhatBAŞ thankyou so much

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 4):

Move the two $.datatable() function calls inside the success functions of each respective calls.

Remember that ajax is async meaning the next line will execute immediately after calling it even if it hasnt returned. We want to make sure the datatable() function only is called when ajax has finished inserting the table data.